# How to add a fine in existing clearcase baseline? (Not the latest baseline)

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is it possible to add a file in existing ClearCase baseline (*Not* the latest baseline) ?

Scenario :

There is a component , say `CC_COMP` having a number of baselines created over time. Consider below baselines in the component `CC_COMP`

```
BL_Latest
BL_New
BL_Older
BL_Oldest
```

There is a file `FILE` already present in `BL_Lastest` which is ONLY version in the VOB.
Now I want to add the same file `FILE` ( logically different but same in name ) in the baseline `BL_Older`.

How can I add that file in that older baseline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: a baseline is, by its very definition, immutable.
See for instance the article "[The power of Unified Change Management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/701.html)"

> These baselines are semantically rich objects that identify a "version" of a UCM component.
>   By using them, you can be certain that all files in that component are associated with the same version.
>   **You can also be certain that the baseline will not change out from under you.
>
>   Once created, UCM baselines are immutable** and can be used for defining higher-level configurations. An entire system, for example, can be assembled from a set of component baselines.

You need to:

- create a substream to the stream where `BL_Older` was created
- rebase or initialize that substream with the `BL_Older` baseline
- add your file (using an UCM view associated with that stream)
- make a new baseline `BL_Older.1` for example.

Comment: The project itself is single stream project. Hence I can't create substream. There are other files in the directory of the baseline BL_Older where I wanted to place the new file having same name. In this case where sub stream can't be created, I think merging the directory ( BL_Older ) should help.

Comment: @HITENC no problem: you can create another UCM project (you don't have to make it single stream this time), and initialize its integration stream with BL_Older.